# Need to show the message after Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Aspose.Cells to download the file and I am using following code

```
workbook.Save(this.Response, wbookName, ContentDisposition.Attachment, new OoxmlSaveOptions());
this.Response.End();
```

Now I want to show a message for download completed on my web page but I am unable to do that. 
How I can show the message on my web page that file has been downloaded?

Comment: You can't. One request equals one response.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why can't you show the message before Response.End?

Comment: Side note: I strongly suspect this is daily delete/repost of the question... If this is the case instead of deleting you should have linked to old question and clarify what was not solved with deleted one.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `Response.End()`, nothing else can be sent to the client. You will have to send anything before the call to `Response.End()`, e.g., by using `Response.Write()`.